# UIActivityViewController showing blank options and can't be interacted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I was implementing new feature with share button on my app. Notice the activityViewController appeared blank. at first i thought the item i gave to share might be null, but when i tried to share a simple string, it still shows up like this, i revisited my old working code, and they are all acting like this. Even something as simple as this:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["test"], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

this is what i got:
[image: iphone X simulator nav screenshot]
Anybody have any idea what is causing this and how to fix this?

EDIT: Tested Using Actual Device, Causing problems, in my released APP, the feedback is that its not showing blank, it is showing with options, just not inter-actable, can't be clicked and can't dismiss it, the app will just "hang" and then the user will have to kill the app to reuse it. After testing, i'm still not sure what is causing the blank, i've disabled all my UIViewController extension,(many of them is not automated and need functions to call anyway so i don't think they are the problem), and when i put a debugPrint in the completion block of the present function, it doesn't even get called so the activity view controller is not finished initializing?

Comment: That probably will not happen on a real device. Your simulator has no applications to display.

Comment: I'm testing it on my actual device, its showing up like this, and then it will crash by itself after 2 mins or so with this : Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Comment: Found the culprit. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally found the culprit, somebody tipped me of that i should look into extension of UIViewController to check if i'm overriding something, well i didn't but i did override UILabel and UIButton's awakeFromNib and setNeedsDisplay because my app have multiple language support and In-App change language support and i wanted to "automate" UILabel and UIButton to change language font(because some font is better looking) so that i can avoid attaching listener to viewcontrollers to change language font when they do in-app language changes.

```
override open func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    if let prefLang = UserDefaults.languageCode{
        self.font = switchFontForLang(lang: prefLang)
    }
}

override open func setNeedsDisplay() {
    super.setNeedsDisplay()
    if let prefLang = UserDefaults.languageCode{
        self.font = switchFontForLang(lang: prefLang)
    }
}
```

Particularly the setNeedsDisplay() is causing problem, i've put a debugmessage in them both and i found out its being called endlessly, my guess is because the "in-app" language font changing is trying to change language to the setting but the UIActivityViewController is somehow trying to change the font back or at the very least calling setNeedsDisplay() when it detects something is not right, which it will call into the overrided method and then it will detect it back again thus creating a loop of endlessly calling setNeedsDisplay().